# Not receiving all text/json data when AJAX webscraping

Tags: python, json, ajax, web-scraping

First time posting a question, I am not an expert python or web developer.

I am creating a web scraper to scrape a dynamic web page. I've walked through a few tutorials and put together a simple web scaper to get started. It works, as in it is retrieving some json. However when inspecting the response in the Chrome dev tools, I see that the json returned is only the first level which the value is 'null'. **How do I get the rest of the values?**

```
import requests

headers = {

"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate",
"origin": "https://www.example.com",
"referer": "https://www.example.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
}

#AJAX Request url from the Chrome dev tools
# data parameter taken from the Chrome dev tools, "Network Tab" >"Headers Tab" > "Request Payload"
r = requests.post('https://www.example.com/api/show', headers = headers,data = {"sort":"trending","page_num":4,"per_page":12,"q":"","tags":[]})


response = r.json()

print(response)
```

Output:

```
{'response':None}
```

The Expected Output should be:

```
{ "response":{ "discoverables":[ { "bullet_point":null,"category": "category_1","category_url":"/url"...
```

I see the above full json expected result in the Chrome dev tools under "Network" > "Response"

I have tried:

- Changing the header values or omitting them with no difference in result
- Trying to utilize GET (this returns status code 404)
- Using request.sessions
- I've tried just printing 'r' and not utilizing .json, which returns `{"response":null}`

Not sure why the rest of the json isn't being captured.

I took a look here: http://toddhayton.com/2015/03/11/scraping-ajax-pages-with-python/
However there is no 'Form Data', as shown in their example. It shows 'Request Payload' instead, and no specified parameters.

I am assuming there is a parameter I am missing to request the rest of the json data. Or having to do with the POST request. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: could be a lot of things... could you post the page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/energy-green-tech?project_type=campaign&project_timing=all&sort=trending  I am trying to scrape the campaign information

Comment: Two things i see immediately, you need to include the x-csrf-token in the header, and change "data" to "json". to get the a valid x-csrf-token, you'll probably want to use request sessions

Comment: I've tried the x-csrf-token header/value previously with no luck. I'll give it a try with sessions and the switch to json.

Comment: Thanks! Making the changes of 'data' to 'json' & including x-csrf-token. Changing to sessions wasn't needed. It looks like some more reading of the requests library was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url=r'https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/energy-green-tech?project_type=campaign&project_timing=all&sort=trending'

s=requests.Session()
r=s.get(url)


soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')

token=soup.find('meta',{'name':'csrf-token'}).attrs['content']
print(token)

dataload={
'category_main': "Energy & Green Tech",
'category_top_level': "Tech & Innovation",
'page_num': 2,
'per_page': 12,
'project_timing': "all",
'project_type': "campaign",
'q': "",
'sort': "trending",
'tags': []

}


headers={
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate",
    'content-length': str(len(json.dumps(dataload, separators=(',',':')))),
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'origin': r'https://www.indiegogo.com',
    'referer': r'https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/energy-green-tech?project_type=campaign&project_timing=all&sort=trending',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrf-token':token,
    'x-locale': 'en'

}

r=s.post(r'https://www.indiegogo.com/private_api/discover',headers=headers,json=dataload)
print(r.json())
```